# How to programatically instantiate a spring boot test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit4

I am looking to instantiate a spring boot test in code.

I have a set of cucumber test, which instantiate my app’s spring context using `@SpringBootTest`, but I am now looking to leverage the same tests and steps code, but to run against my deployed app.

So I am looking to:

- check a system property
- instantiate a my local context in a `SpringBootTest` environment if system property set
- instantiate a different `SpringBootTest` context which hits a live instance of my service.

Does anybody have any recommendations on how to do that?

P.S.

I use spring boot for my service, junit4 and maven.

Comment: dont know where is your deployed app, but if it is  in a ecosystem that have maven, you could  refer to this question answers : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238149/how-to-configure-pom-to-run-tests-packaged-in-a-jar

Comment: This useful guide : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

Comment: @MohammedHousseynTaleb when I say deployed I mean a live running instance of my app in a docker container - it could be running anywhere it could also not be a java app at all!

Answer (score 0):

Ovarall, all Junit test setting still working in spring boot.

1. you can use below methods for your setting/configuration before overall testing

   @BeforeClass
   public static void setUpClass() {
       System.out.println("@BeforeClass setUpClass");
       myExpensiveManagedResource = new ExpensiveManagedResource();
   }

   @AfterClass
   public static void tearDownClass() throws IOException {
       System.out.println("@AfterClass tearDownClass");
       myExpensiveManagedResource.close();
       myExpensiveManagedResource = null;
   }
2. you can also do configuration for each method

   @Before
   public void setUp() {
       this.println("@Before setUp");
       this.myManagedResource = new ManagedResource();
   }

   @After
   public void tearDown() throws IOException {
       this.println("@After tearDown");
       this.myManagedResource.close();
       this.myManagedResource = null;
       this.println("   ");
   }

Comment: my goal is not to instantiate my context at all, because that will require to open up ports, connects to databases, kafka etc.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you can ingest your live instance of service in the @BeforeClass method.