# Run maven tests without maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium, maven-surefire-plugin

I have maven project witch run selenium tests with maven-surefire-plugin.

Is it possible to run selenium tests without maven? For example

```
java -jar myTestLib.jar ...some params
```

I plan release my tests library and run tests with different parameters later.

Thank you.

Comment: just create executable jar with some CLI param.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238149/how-to-configure-pom-to-run-tests-packaged-in-a-jar